# Call a function inside store.subscribe in react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to call a function inside a the `store.subscribe` and i always get an error: `undefined this`,

This is the code that i was trying :

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.GetFilteredData();
}

GetFilteredData = () => {
  WithHoldTaxApi.GetFilteredData()
    .then((collection) => {
      console.log("data", collection)
      this.setState({ collection: collection })
    }
    ).catch(error => {
      throw error;
    })
}

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState())
  this.GetFilteredData();
})
```

Comment: can you provide more of your code? Where is `GetFilteredData` defined?

Comment: Can you please add the code where you are using this function

Comment: Please try `store.subscribe(function() {` instead of `store.subscribe(() => {`. I think it will work.

Comment: @huynhsamha  i have just tried i am still getting :TypeError: Cannot read property 'GetFilteredData' of undefined
(anonymous function)

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald can you take a look i added the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to do something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.subscribe();
}

GetFilteredData = () => {
  WithHoldTaxApi.GetFilteredData()
    .then((collection) => {
      console.log("data", collection)
      this.setState({ collection: collection })
    }
    ).catch(error => {
      throw error;
    })
}

subscribe = () => {
  store.subscribe(() => {
     console.log(store.getState())
     this.GetFilteredData();
  })
}
```